# How to replace only first sequential occurences (fuzzymatch)?

Tags: javascript, regex, fuzzy-search

I'm trying to write "fuzzy" match and I can't find a way to solve this problem:

Data in: `makrusakkk`, query: `mrk`, expected result: `<b>m</b>ak<b>r</b>usa<b>k</b>kk`.

RegExp: `"makrusakkk".match(/(m).*?(r).*?(k)/i)` returns `["makrusak", "m", "r", "k"]`.

So the question is: is there a way to get the expected result using RegExp?

Comment: This problem seems solvable with simple looping. Why regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using regular expression for such problem makes things just more complicated. The following string and loop based solution would lead to the result:

```
function fuzzySearch(query, input) {
    var inds = patternMatches(query, input);
    if(!inds) return input;

    var result = input;
    for(var i = inds.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var index = inds[i];
        result = result.substr(0,index) + 
            "<b>" + result[index] + "</b>" + 
            result.substr(index+1);
    }

    return result;
}

function patternMatches(query, input) {
    if(query.length <= 0) {
        return [];
    } else if(query.length == 1) {
        if(input[0] == query[0]) return [0];
        else return [];
    } else {
        if(input[0] != query[0])
        return false;

        var inds = [0];
        for(var i = 1; i < query.length; i++) {
            var foundInd = input.indexOf(query[i], inds[i-1]);
            if(foundInd < 0) {
                return [];
            } else {
                inds.push(foundInd);
            }
        }
        return inds;        
    }
}

var input = "makrusakkksd";
var query = "mrk";
console.log(fuzzySearch(query, input));
console.log(patternMatches(query, input));
```

Here's a live demo too: http://jsfiddle.net/sinairv/T2MF4/

Comment: Very nice alternative solution. One fix: input is `makrusakkk` (triple K) and your code marks `<b>` last occurence of K, but should _first_.

Comment: This is purposeful. I thought the aim of "mrk" is to filter words starting with "m", ending with "k" and having "r" in between. Marking the first occurrance of "k" makes the code even simpler and cleaner!

Comment: okay, thx. It's not a RegExp, but it fits needs. Marked as solution.

Comment: @mjey solving this problem with regex is like above, but not a wise solution at all. We would have to do the same string based loops to generate the regular expression first. Then after finding the matches, again we have to loop through found matched groups just like above to form the result. It would take twice the effort as above solution, with lots more runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Here you will need `for`:

```
function search_for_it(txt, arr){
    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        var reg = new RegExp(arr[i], "i");
        txt = txt.replace(reg, "<b>"+arr[i]+"</b>");
    }
    return txt;
}

search_for_it("makrusakkk", ["m","r","k"]);

//return "<b>m</b>a<b>k</b><b>r</b>usakkk"
```

PS: Your *expected result* is incorrect. There is a `k` after the first `a`.

Comment: The think the OP meant that "mrk" was to be dealt with in sequence, hence the first 'k' is not to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to get an expected result using RegExp?

There is.

```
"makrusakkk".replace(/(m)(.*?)(r)(.*?)(k)/i, '<b>$1</b>$2<b>$3</b>$4<b>$5</b>'​​​​​​​)
```

Comment: Huh. It's simple if we do manual replace, but i need **function** - e.g. input args is different each time.

Answer (score 0):

I feel vaguely dirty for this, but...regardless; here's *one* way to do it:

```
$('#s').keyup(

function(e) {
    var w = e.which;
    if (w == 8 || w == 46) {
        return false;
    }
    var listElems = $('ul:first li'),
        search = $(this).val().replace(/w+/g, ''),
        r = search.split(''),
        rString = [];
    $.each(r, function(i, v) {
        rString.push('(' + v + ')');
    });
    var reg = new RegExp(rString.join('(\\d|\\D)*'), 'gi');

    listElems.each(

    function() {
        if (!$(this).attr('data-origtext')) {
            $(this).attr('data-origtext', $(this).text());
        }
        $(this).html($(this).attr('data-origtext').replace(reg, '<b>$&</b>'));
    });
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nYNw6/).

It could, almost certainly, benefit from quite some simplification though.

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).
- [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/).
- [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
- [`RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).